# Location of config in an OpenCart extension

Tags: php, opencart

I am currently developing OpenCart extensions. I am looking through existing extensions to understand the architecture (and familiarizing MVC/PHPOO concepts).

Frequently, this line of code comes up:

> $seller_email = $this->config->get('service_seller_email');

My interpretation based on reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru/13484904#13484904) thread:

I understand that this is a variable assignment, where it's accessing a model (?) called `config` to retrieve a string called `service_seller_email` from the admin settings portal. However, I have tried navigating through the various MVC folders within OpenCart, and I could not find a specific `config.php`. Could you please correct my interpretation if it's wrong?

EDIT: To add to the confusion, the article I linked specifies that you need to `load` a `config` in a controller before using it, like `$this->language->load('product/search');`, but I cannot find a line such as `$this->config->load('...');` or the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation is incorrect. The *config* class is not considered as model (despite it is accessing DB directly) but as a *system library* class - that's why you can find it under `system/library/` folder.

OpenCart has it's implementation of [*service locator* (registry)](https://www.google.com/search?q=service+locator+pattern) which is used to to *store* the config object so that you can access it directly from anywhere (inside of OpenCart of course).

It is loaded in both `index.php` files (in root and under `admin/`) like this:

```
$config = new Config();
$registry->set('config', $config);
```

This `$registry` is our service locator and it is passed over to any controller in it's `__construct()` method. Each controller has also a magic method `__get()` which is responsible for retrieving objects from this `$registry` - take a look at abstract Controller class at `system/engine/controller.php` which each controller extends (and should extend).

That's why you can freely call directly

```
$this->config->get('some_config_key');
```

The first part, `$this->config` will fall into the `__get()` method passing over the `'config'` value as a `$key` which in turn is passed over to next call

```
return $this->registry->get($key);
```

And since the config object is registered under `'config'` key in our service locator, it is retrieved and returned so that we could call `get('some_config_key')` on it.

Now the `some_config_key` key is stored in DB in `setting` table and the config object tries to find it and get it's value (you can take a look at how this works in `system/library/config.php`).

Hopefully this clarifies your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [docs](http://wiki.opencarthelp.com/doku.php?id=method_config_get), it looks like the config values are stored in the `setting` table. The `Config` class itself is located in `/system/library/config.php`.

Comment: Hi @isim. It seems my payment extension `alipay` is missing in this directory, yet my "configurations" are still saved. Could it be in another location?

Comment: Not sure if I followed.. if you want to build a new payment extension, shouldn't all your codes go into the `payment` folders like `catalog/controller/payment/`, `catalog/model/payment/` etc. for the Catalog side, and `admin/controller/payment/` etc. for the Admin side?

Comment: They are all in those directories you mentioned - but I cannot find files relating to both my extension and config.

Comment: Hmmm strange... my `admin/*` and `catalog/*` folders are at the same level as my `/systen/library/*` folder. Have you seen this [tutorial](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=113&t=30653) on creating opencart payment extension?

Comment: They are in the same level as mine as well.

Comment: If your configurations are saved, then they are probably in the `setting` (or `oc_setting`) table. Have you checked there?

Answer (score 0):

In `admin > index.php` you wil find

```
// Config
$config = new Config();
$registry->set('config', $config);
```

That's where it is initialized. The class is located in

```
system > library > config.php
```

Config loaded in `system > engine >loader.php`:

```
public function config($config) {
    $this->config->load($config);
}
```